# How do I increase the font size in SSIS?

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I have a new windows instance on which I am running SSIS and the font sizes are so tiny I have to squint my eyes to see the names and text. Is there a way to increase the text font size ? Now I have tried the tools > options > fonts and colors but I do not know which option to select from the drop down to increase the size of the text on canvas.

[SSIS canvas with the tiny text](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UGurl.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Go to Tools -> Options - > Environment -> Fonts and Colors
Select "Business Intelligence Designers"

Here you can set the font and the size.
Have a look at the screenshot [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5GXja.png)